# I see frequent PTR requests in my wireshark capture, are they normal?

Tags: dns, wireshark

Lately I've been getting very frequent DNS lookup failuers (I use Google's dns servers) so I set up wireshark to see some of the traffic and I see many PTR requests for IP's that don't seem relevant.

Sample screenshot here: [http://i.imgur.com/M9wtDQq.png](https://i.imgur.com/M9wtDQq.png)  (192.168.1.1 is my router and 192.168.1.100 is my main PC where wireshark is running)

- I've disabled name resolution in wireshark
- I've run an anti virus scan and gmer

What could be the source of those PTR queries? Basically I'm concerned that I have some rogue program doing too many requests and occasionally the DNS server blocks my legitimate requests as a flood protection mechanism.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Are you running any services, like Apache, that might be doing Reverse-DNS on their log files?

Comment: @heavyd I'm using Windows 7 and I don't run any services that should be doing that or at least I can't really think of any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit, it was [glasswire](https://www.glasswire.com/).